# Trying to rename files with glob and os modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files with the glob and os modules, but I'm not getting anywhere. I've looked for some solutions but not found any. "Cannot create a file when that file already exists.".

And if I get that to work, I'm not sure how to rename multiple items, say I have three pictures called img_1001, img_1002, and img_1003. How could I rename these to something like: picture_1, picture_2, and picture_3.

Here is my code at the moment.

```
import os
import glob

x = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Verzo\Desktop\New folder\*.txt")

for filename in x:
    os.rename(filename, "Picture ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for filename in x:
        os.rename(filename, "Picture ")
```

The script is trying to rename every file in that list to `Picture`. This will not work, as you discovered.

The following code is untested.

```
    import os
    from glob import glob

    for number, filename in enumerate(glob(r"C:\Users\Verzo\Desktop\New folder\*.txt")):
        try:
            os.rename(filename, "Picture_{0}".format(number))
        except OSError as e:
            print("Something happened:", e)
```

Comment: If the original names indicate an ordering, you may want to keep that order. Use `sorted(glob ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that (untested)

```
import os
import glob

x = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Verzo\Desktop\New folder\*.txt")

for filename in x:
    name, num = filename.split('_')
    num = int(num)
    os.rename(filename, 'picture_%d' % num)
```

Comment: This code is not very robust: It will only work if *every* filename that matches the glob contains an underscore (and only one). Go with @riamse's answer.